# Angular + Bootstrap: Pass a parameter from Typescript to a stylesheet and use this in a @if to determine styles

Tags: css, angular, typescript

**Pre-History**

Our system is a setup of Angular 11 with Bootstrap 5. Lately I have been working with theming our system.

Determining the background color has been a real challenge all the way, but I have solved it by implementing this in my typescript:

```
document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #FFFFFF');
```

This feels like I am implementing a minor "hack" to overcome a challenge rather than programming at a professional level.

**Case:**

I am able to determine the background color in a much prettier way using the global variables offered by Bootstrap. By altering the global variable `$body-bg` I am able to set the background color in `styles.scss`.

As I am working with themes, I do not want to set the background color to one color and keep it there forever. I need to be able to change the background color with the rest of the styles. However, I cannot find any method of passing the variable of which theme is active to the stylesheet. What I want to do is displayed below:

```
 @if $activeTheme == "dark" {
    $body-bg: #000;
  }
```

**Challenge:**

I cannot find any method of passing on the variable `@activeTheme` from my `theme-service.ts` to the `styles.scss` to be used in a `@if`.

I've been looking all over for a solution to this problem, but have not been able to find any topics with this exact case. That might mean I am on the moon in my thinking of how I want to solve the background challenge.

Can this be done?
I am open to any other solutions to theming the background of body :)

Comment: Sass is compiled. It can't be changed at runtime.

Use css variables. And change the value of the variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: I was trying to do the impossible. That explains why I had such a hard time with this approach.

I'll investigate into your suggested approach. Thank you for your reply :)